# Laravel - Filter records by distinct relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Right now I have the following models structure,

`Country -> State -> City -> Student`

And the `Student` model includes `first_name` and `last_name`.

So, I want countries to by filtered by giving student's first name. Like if I give `John` then I want list of countries which has students whose first name is `John`.

I was trying something like this,

I added a method called `Students()` in `Country` model and returning `Student` instances from that method. But now I stuck to find out how to filter countries.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342275/laravel-eloquent-relation-issue-for-multiple-tables

Comment: your student table have country_id or city_id?

Comment: @DsRaj Only city_id

Comment: Okay and you want the country list of the student whose name starts with John
Let say: Name: John Dark Country: UK, Name:John Due Country: US right

Comment: @DsRaj Yeah, right

Comment: @GauravDeshpande check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar question recently and I came with the following solution myself. Probably, there are easier ways, but this will get you going for now, I guess.

First we query all the users with `first_name` == `John`, as you described, and we limit the query to output only the ID's.

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'John')->get()->pluck('id');
```

We then cross-compare this with the result of `Students()` from the country model. As I don't know what you're querying for to get the country that you want, I'll just take the Netherlands as an example — that's where I'm from.

```
$users = Country::where('name', 'the Netherlands')->students()->whereIn('id', $users)->get();
```

For this to work, you must make sure that within the `Students()`-function in your model, the `get()` is left out.

**Final 'result':**

```
$users = User::where('first_name', 'John')->get()->pluck('id');
$users = Country::where('name', 'the Netherlands')->students()->whereIn('id', $users)->get();
```

Comment: I did the same as you told but it's throwing an `BadMethodCallException` exception, `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::students does not exist`.

Comment: Could you please show me the `Students()` method you have created on your country model?

(Referring to what you've said here: "I added a method called Students() in Country model and returning Student instances from that method.")

Answer (score 0):

in the Student Model create this:

```
public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class,'city_id', 'id');
    }
```

and in the City Model create this:

```
public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class,'state_id', 'id');
    }
```

Finally in the State Model:

```
public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id', 'id');
    }
```

For example if you made things like that in controller:

```
$students = Student::where('name', 'John')->get();
```

in the view:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
$student->city->state->country->country_name;
@endforeach
```

You can access like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup the model and relationship properly then you need to call them using in with function

```
$students = Student::where('name','John')->with('city.state.country')->get();
```

Loop through the `$students`

```
@foreach($students as $student)
     {{ $student->city->state->country }}
@endif
```